# AsyncTask always Running and it is not finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my class that i have extended from `Asynctask`:

```
public class HttpAsyncTaskSendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public interface SendDataCallback {
        void onComplete(AsyncTask task,String nidSave, String guid);

        void onError(String msg);
    }
    ...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        return PostJson.POST(urls[0], urls[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            if (result != null) {
    ...
              dataCallback.onComplete(this,res.getString("NidSave"), guid);

                } else {
                    dataCallback.onError("No response from server");
                }
            }
   ....
        }
```

I am using this class in my activity like this:

```
sendDataQueue.add(httpAsyncTaskSendData = new HttpAsyncTaskSendData(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Guid")),
        cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("SendStateGps")), datasource, database1
        , Housing, new HttpAsyncTaskSendData.SendDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(AsyncTask task ,String nidSave, String guid) {
        if (task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) &&
                !nidSave.equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")) {
            sendDataQueue.remove(task);
        } else {
            queueHasError = true;
        }

        if (!queueHasError) {
            if (sendDataQueue.size() == 0) {
                SendGps(nidSave, guid);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String msg) {
        queueHasError = true;
        toastError(DetailsActivity.this, msg);
    }
}).executeOnExecutor((AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR),
        AppUtil.getConfig(DetailsActivity.this,
                MainActivity.SETTING_GEO_SERVICE) + "SaveVisit/",
        json.toString()));
```

My question is why on `onComplete` callback when i check Asyncktask status , this is in `Running` mode? and it is not in `Finnish`.

My `onComplete` callback called on `onPostExecute` and in this section my task should be finished its job!!! but still is running? What's is happen and what's my problem?
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't set the priority of the AsyncTask thread.  That single thread is a shared resource for all AsyncTasks in your app.  If you need to set priority, use a Thread.

Comment: Do not make your interface inside the HttpAsyncTaskSendData class. Because when you implement your interface is bind to the HttpAsyncTaskSendData object and it never dies

Comment: @MushahidGillani can you say and example that the best way for creating and using an interface on async class?

Comment: just make your interface outside of this HttpAsyncTaskSendData class.

Comment: or declare it `static`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPostExecute` is not yet finished, thus the state of the `AsyncTask` is not FINISH

[`AsyncTask.Status`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status)

> FINISHED
>   Indicates that AsyncTask.onPostExecute(Result) has finished.

Comment: Then when i have to call onComplete callaback on my async class?

Comment: @sayres kabir in `onPostExecute` only

Comment: `onPostExecute` is absolutely correct. I am wondering why you check for the execution state in your `onComplete`. If you are calling this function only from `onPostExecute`, your background process as defined in your `doInBackground()` is finished anyway. If you want to catch the case `result==null` than return that in `onError`, because you mix the good case with an error case in your `onComplete` which is bad practise.

Comment: @prashant17 dude, did you see my code? I called my callback on `onPostExecute`

Comment: @DenisLoh this is part of my code.on `onPostExecute` i am using sqlite and i need to do in ui thread

Comment: @sayres kabir in `onPostExecute` only No need to check for `AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED`

Comment: Please explain, why you want to check if the AsyncTask has finished? The case that `queueHasErrors=true`will never happen, because `doInBackground` must return sometime to actually call `onPostExecute`. If not so, you would have a memory leak because of a never ending thread.

Comment: @prashant17 as you can see on my code i have a list of asynctask class called `sendDataQueue`.I want to this task deleted from my list so in order i need to know this task is finished or not..if finished i delete task from list

Comment: @DenisLoh I explain above but I need to know this task's job finished or not? if finished i remove this task from my list

Comment: If you simply hold a reference to that task in a list, you can just remove that item. The GC will remove your task when there is no further reference on it. However, you must be sure, that there is actually no hidden reference, so use `WeakReferences` when you try to pass the `AsyncTask`. `onPostExecute` - as I said multiple times no, will only be called, when `doInBackground` has fnished.

Comment: @DenisLoh I'll try your suggestion and i''ll announce you